# I want the rights to the photos taken of models I pick

Tags: legal, copyright

I want to make my calendar of men. What do I need for model release of the photos to me? what is a far price to pay the photographer and models? Would I have rights to the photos?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the men are all the age of majority in your area, you simply have to have them sign an "adult" release form or liability waiver. It allows you to use the images how you like (within reasonable limits).

If you, yourself, take the photos (or cause the photos to be taken in your studio, or otherwise control the shoot), you are the owner and have full copyright to the images, at least in most countries. In the US you can register the copyright, but this is not strictly necessary, and is not required anywhere else I can recall.

What you can *do* with the images commercially and morally, is a different issue.

But, this is a complicated area, especially if the work requires multiple models, if they are getting paid, and what their moral rights, legally, happen to be. I suspect a local photography club in your area would be able to help, as would talking to a real lawyer.

There are nuances that don't allow me (not a lawyer, only familiar with the laws that pertain to commercial photography in my locale, etc.) to make stronger statements, other than you *generally* own the photos you take, and *generally* can do what you want with them, within the limits of liability and liability waivers.

> What do I need for model release of the photos to me?

You need them to sign a release form for either adults or minors, depending on their age. A release form is also called a "liability waiver", and if you search the web for those terms you will find many examples you can just borrow.

> what is a far price to pay the photographer and models?

Good question. No idea. I suspect this depend on your locale and the local market. Again, a local photo club might have a better idea.

Comment: It occurs to me that some of the related links to the right probably already answer this better than me. I can remove this answer if one of those are more appropriate.